# CakePHP Page not redirect properly

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, sql-update

Hi I am using CakePHP version 2.x

my problem is page not redirect properly after update the data.

Here is my code-

```
public function addpage() {
  if($this->request->is('post')){         
    if($this->Cmspage->save($this->request->data)){
      $this->Session->setFlash('Data Updated successfully', 'success_message');
      $this->redirect('http://www.xyz.com/appadmins/cms');
    }
  }
}
```

After submit the form the data updated successfully in the table. I think this line is working fine `$this->Cmspage->save($this->request->data)` working properly then after the page is not redirect properly and page is showing blank.

When i am giving comment line of the code the page is working

Here is Code -

```
public function addpage() {
  if($this->request->is('post')){         
    //if($this->Cmspage->save($this->request->data)){
      $this->Session->setFlash('Data Updated successfully', 'success_message');
      $this->redirect('http://www.xyz.com/appadmins/cms');
    //}
  }
}
```

Please help me

Thanks...

Comment: May be add a slash before appadmins like this   $this->redirect(HTTP_ROOT.'/appadmins/cms'); and then try?

Comment: I have changed my code. Please check again. HTTP_ROOT was return `http://www.xyz.com/`

Comment: what is a link of the blank page ? the flash message appear ? success_message is an element ?

Comment: No message appear. displaying blank page.  link - `http://www.xyz.com/cmspages/addpage`

Comment: what is success_message ?

Comment: There is no error and success message. Page is showing white blank. and blank page link - `http://www.xyz.com/cmspages/addpage`

Comment: Hello @ColoO yes success_message is an element.

Comment: success_message is created inside the view > element > success_message.ctp

Comment: maybe $this->Cmspage->save($this->request->data) return false?

Comment: don't know, i have a similar  form for my blog and it's work fine. Past your appcontroller and your mysql file config plz

Comment: Do you find your problem ?

Comment: No.... Can you help me??

Comment: Hello @user2964568 i got return true.

Answer (score 0):

Seeking similar errors on the web. I found some similar answers.

1. The first answer was ue to space just before

   The second solution was to remove?> At the end of model.php

You have your degug at 2 ?

I can give you links if you are interested but they are French websites ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'appadmins', 'action' => 'cms'));
```